# Incomplete import in the generated_plugin_registrant.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a plugin created using the federated approach. The problem is that the `generated_plugin_registrant.dart` contains an incomplete import which is pointing to the app-facing package but leaves out the dart file name and this causes an error.

```dart
import 'package:my_plugin/'; // PROBLEMATIC LINE
import 'package:my_plugin_web/my_plugin_web.dart';

import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  .registerWith(registrar); // PROBLEMATIC LINE
  MyPluginWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

This code is in the default example app for a plugin with an unchanged default `pubspec.yaml`.

Here's the `pubspec.yaml` for the app-facing "my_plugin" package:

```yaml
name: my_plugin
description: A new flutter plugin project.
version: 0.0.1
author:
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
  flutter: '>=1.20.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_plugin_platform_interface:
    path: ../my_plugin_platform_interface
  my_plugin_web:
    path: ../my_plugin_web

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:  
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: com.example.my_plugin
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      web:
        defaultPackage:
          path: my_plugin_web
```

I've tried all the usual commands like `flutter clean` and recreating the project but to no avail.

Comment: I'm getting this too. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Under your web definition (which Google wants in a separate project you have to specify it as
web:
pluginClass: The class name of your web class here
fileName: The file name of the file that holds your web class here

I had it has just "file" and yours is "path" which will cause this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that plugin support for the web was not generated for a specific package or packages.

Try creating an analysis_options.dart and add these lines

```
analyzer:
 exclude: [lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart]
```

then configure your vscode/.settings.json with these lines

`"dart.analysisExcludedFolders":["./yourApp/lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Just find the answer, basically you need to use default_package to specify your are using the integrated plugin. More [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106467)